# Can't get the same data and plot in Python as it is in Mathematica

Tags: python, wolfram-mathematica

I wrote this code in Mathematica and it runs without any problems
'''

```
u = 9.27*10^-21; k = 
 1.38*10^-16; j1 = 3.5; j2 = 1.2; nrr = 9740; nrm = -131180; nmm = \
1072770; na = 6*10^23;
(*d=42.807;*)
i1 = 7; i2 = 1.92;
x = 0.5;
mtdata = {};
m1data = {};
m2data = {};
dmtdata = {};
dsdata = {};
Do[
 mg1Data[h11] = {}; mg2Data[h11] = {};
 mgData[h11] = {};
 dmt[h11] = {};
 ds[h11] = {};
 For[t1 = 1, t1 <= 600, t1++,
  While[True, 
   h1 = h11 + (1 - x)*nrr*i1 + 2*nrm*i2;
   h2 = h11 + (1 - x)*nrm*i1 + 2*nmm*i2;
   x1 = (7*u*h1)/(k t1);
   x2 = (1.92*u*h2)/(k t1);
   x3 = 2*j1; x4 = 2*j2; 
   q1 = (x3 + 1)/x3; q2 = (x4 + 1)/x4;
   m1 = 7*(q1*Coth[q1*x1] - (1/x3)*Coth[x1/x3]);
   m2 = 1.92*(q2*Coth[q2*x2] - (1/x4)*Coth[x2/x4]);
   m = Abs[(1 - x)*m1 + 2*m2];
   If[Abs[m1 - i1] < 10^-7 && Abs[m2 - i2] < 10^-7,
    AppendTo[mgData[h11], {t1, m}];
    AppendTo[mg1Data[h11], {t1, m1}];
    AppendTo[mg2Data[h11], {t1, m2}];  
    Break[],
    i1 = m1; i2 = m2
    ]
   ]
  ];
 int = Interpolation[mgData[h11]];
 dmt[h11] = Table[{t, Derivative[1][int][t]}, {t, 1, 600, 1}];
 ds[h11] = 
  Table[{t, -NIntegrate[
      10^-7*na*u*Derivative[1][int][t], {h, 0, h11}]}, {t, 10, 600, 
    15}];
 AppendTo[mtdata, mgData[h11]];
 AppendTo[m1data, mg1Data[h11]];
 AppendTo[m2data, mg2Data[h11]];
 AppendTo[dmtdata, dmt[h11]];
 AppendTo[dsdata, ds[h11]];
 mgData[h11] = {};
 mg1Data[h11] = {};
 mg2Data[h11] = {};
 dmt[h11] = {};
 ds[h11] = {};
 , {h11, {10000, 20000}}]

ListPlot[Join[Table[mtdata[[i]], {i, Length[mtdata]}], 
  Table[m1data[[i]], {i, Length[m1data]}], 
  Table[m2data[[i]], {i, Length[m2data]}]], Joined -> True, 
 Frame -> True, 
 FrameLabel -> {"Temprature K", 
   "M \!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(\[Mu]\), \(B\)]\)/f.u"}]
```

'''
To give an output figure like this
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bGEDZ.png)

but when I try to write the same code in python it gives error (division by zero) and some times it takes to much time running and no output appears. I wrote the code such that I add my data in a list inside dictionary and the key is changing with the iterator variable. here is my python code

'''

```
import numpy as np 
#from decimal import Decimal, getcontext
import math
import mpmath as mp
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import scipy as cp 

u = 9.27*10.0**(-21) 
k =1.38*10.0**(-16)
j1 = 3.5
j2 = 1.2
nrr = 9740
nrm = -131180
nmm = 1072770
na = 6*10.0**(23)
i1 = 7
i2 = 1.92
x = 0.5

m1data={}
m2data={}
mtdata={}
dmtdata={}
dsdata={}

for h11 in range(10_000, 20_001, 10_000):
    m1data["m1_%s" %h11]=[]
    m2data["m2_%s" %h11]=[]
    mtdata["mt_%s" %h11]=[]
    dmtdata["dmt_%s" %h11]=[]
    dsdata["ds_%s" %h11]=[]
    for t1 in range(1,601,1):
        while True: 
            h1 = h11 + (1-x)*nrr*i1 + 2*nrm*i2
            h2 = h11 + (1-x)*nrm*i1 + 2*nmm*i2
            x1 = (i1*u*h1)/(k*t1)
            x2 = (i2*u*h2)/(k*t1)
            x3 = 2*j1
            x4 = 2*j2
            q1 = (x3+1)/x3
            q2 = (x4+1)/x4
            m1 = i1*(q1*mp.coth(q1*x1)-(1/x3)*mp.coth(x1/x3))
            m2 = i2*(q2*mp.coth(q2*x2)-(1/x4)*mp.coth(x2/x4))
            m = abs((1-x)*m1 + 2*m2)
            if (abs(abs(m1)-i1)<10**(-7) and abs(abs(m2)-i2)<10**(-7)):
                m1data["m1_%s" %h11].append(m1)
                m2data["m2_%s" %h11].append(m2)
                mtdata["mt_%s" %h11].append(m)
                break
            else:
                i1 = m1
                i2 = m2
```

'''

Comment: Your two versions of the code are very similar. You only have /(k t1), /x4, /x3. Can you put a guard on the calculations of those three and name which one equals zero when it happens?

Comment: The zero comes from m1 in  python code

Comment: That helps. Thank you. Looking at the almost completely horizontal lines in the plot of Coth and considering your large + and - exponents I am guessing that you are experiencing what is called "catastrophic cancellation" which is two numbers being really close to each other and when you subtract them the result ends up being 0.0 in the available floating point math. Is there any way you could get 64 bit or even 256 bit floating point numbers in your Python code?  That might show you the result is wildly tiny, but not exactly zero. MMA floating point isn't other PL, or even Intel, FP

Comment: Actually I am on linux and 64-bit machine so the default for int or float is 64-bit precision. But the code runs without any problems in Mathematica and the out put of m1,  m2 and m is not that small. the smallest value in Mathematica out put is about 0.1 or above.

Comment: Mathematica floating point is not the same as Intel floating point or IEEE floating point and I have no idea where Python floating point sits in that spectrum. People report struggling with Mathematica's version of floating point when coming from anything else. Your first response to me said that the zero came from `m1` and I saw that came from subtracting two `coth` so that is what led me to guess cancellation. If that isn't the source of the problem then I hope I didn't waste any of your time hunting for this.